# In Java, how can I instantiate a generic class with another type variable as the type?

Tags: java, java-7

In the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), I read that "A type variable [of a generic class] can be any non-primitive type you specify: any class type, any interface type, any array type, or even **another type variable**."

In other words, given this:

```
class Box<T> {
    private T t;
    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
    public T get() { return t; }
}
```

I can do this, as written:

```
Box<Object> box1 = new Box<>();
Box<Serializable> box2 = new Box<>();
Box<Comparable<Object>> box3 = new Box<>();
Box<char[]> box4 = new Box<>();
```

But what about a type variable?  What would "another type variable" even mean at compile time?

```
// nothing like this works
// Box<Z> box5 = new Box<>();
// Box<<Z>> box5 = new Box<>();
// Box<Z> box5 = new Box<Z>();
// Box<<Z>> box5 = new Box<<Z>>();
```

Comment: _Inside_ a generic class or method, that defines the type `Z` you can use it to create other generic types. For example in `Box<T>` you could create a `List<T>`. The same rules apply as for other variables - it needs to be **defined** and **in scope**.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's referring to a case where it is used inside of another generic class, like this:

```
class SomeGenericClass<T> {
    Box<T> box = new Box<T>();
}
```

Where `T` is another type variable and you could construct the object like this:

```
SomeGenericClass<Object> someGenericClass = new SomeGenericClass<>();
```

Where the `box` initialized in `SomeGenericClass` is a `Box<Object>`

It could also be referring to using another generic instance inside your generic class like this:

```
class Box<T> {
    ArrayList<T> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And constructing the class like this:

```
Box<Object> box = new Box<>();
```

Where the `ArrayList` inside `Box<Object>` would be a `ArrayList<Object>`

Answer (score 1):

It means if you have another class that uses generics you can set the type to another type variable from  that class, so something like this:

```
public class A<S>{
  private B<S>();

}

public class B<T>{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
Box <T> extends SomeParametrizedClass<T>{
// class body
private List<T> someList;
}
```

Here you have parametrized field and superclass with variable types instead of specifically provided types.